# Adding a filegroup to flyway_schema_history table using MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, flyway

Using Mssql I want to create the flyway_schema_history table on a given filegroup instead of primary.  Is there any way I can accomplish getting the flyway_schema_history table to appear in a different filegroup when using mssql?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no built-in way. You have to manually create the table to accomplish this.

Update: This will be supported from Flyway 6.0.0 onwards.